# authenticating ldap linux server client with windows server

Tags: amazon-ec2, active-directory, ldap, openldap, aws-devops

In our organization we have 3 servers running on aws, one of linux main server with ldap account manager (LAM) configured on it. And other two are (linux client server and windows server).             I've configured linux client server with (LAM) and also able to authenticate (lAM users with linux client server)  but facing issue in authentication of LAM users with windows server ec2 machine. please help me in this regard if community has better solution for it. thanks!!!

i tried different methods just like Microsoft AD domain service but not get result

Comment: LDAP alone can't be leveraged for Windows integrated authentication. You need Kerberos/NTLM. How are you expecting the windows server to authenticate users and what have you done to configure it? Do you have a domain controller? Is the Windows server joined to the domain?

Comment: I have used a domain controller but it is not picking up clients on the same ntework

Comment: Did you join the Windows server to the domain controller? Is the DC configured to use your LDAP directory for auth? Are authorized domain users/groups configured for the server? What makes you say the DC is not "picking up clients on the same network"? what do you mean exactly by that?